# Select behavior different between pyspark 2.4.8 and 3.3.2

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Recently, one of job failed after we upgraded the cluster from version 2.4.8 to 3.3.2 of Apache Spark.

Below is an example to reproduce the issue.

Here I am creating two datasets with 3 columns each. Two columns are common between them colA and colB.

```
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

df_current_data = [("abc.com","SA1","1"), \
   ("def.com","SA2","1"), \
   ("ee.com","SA3","1")
]
df_current_data_cols = ["colA", "colB", "2023-10-10"]
curr_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=df_current_data, schema = df_current_data_cols)

df_historical_data = [("zzz.com","SAz","1"), \
   ("yyy.com","SA2","y"), \
   ("ee.com","SA3","1")
]
df_historical_data_cols = ["colA", "colB", "2022-09-09"]
his_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=df_historical_data, schema = df_historical_data_cols)
```

Here is a function, where I perform a full outer join between the two datasets.
Notice the "select" after the join. The goal is to get the following columns "colA", "colB", "2023-10-10", "2022-09-09". The code inside select statement will return ["colA", "colB", "colA", "colB", "2023-10-10", "2022-09-09"]. Till this point, both spark versions are behaving the same.

```
def append_to_existing_output(df_current_data: DataFrame, df_historical_data: DataFrame):
   joined_df_with_duplicate_columns = (df_current_data.alias("left")
        .join(df_historical_data.alias("right"), ["colA", "colB"],
              how="full_outer")
    .select(["colA", "colB", "left.*"] +
        df_historical_data.drop(*df_current_data.columns).columns))
   return joined_df_with_duplicate_columns
```

Here, I call the function and pass the dataframes

```
append_to_existing_output(curr_df, his_df).show()
```

Here is the interesting part:

The below picture is from Spark 2.4.8 showing the output and plan. Notice that it auto removed the duplicate colA and colB. It also did it correctly since it did not remove the coalesce columns after the join but rather the normal colA.

[image]

The below picture is from Spark 3.3.2. I run the same code but the output contains the extra columns and the plan also shows that.

[image]

I understand that doing left.* was not the best idea.

The question I have is in which spark PR this logic was changed and why? Is the previous version of Spark running distinct on column list (in specific cases) and now not? Which Spark version is showing correct behavior?

Comment: In such cases I would suggest to create alias of left and right tables and select columns you want according to business logic and rename them. It is better to be explicit. It is most likely this behaviour was changed in newer spark to be more explicit and leave it to the enduser to choose what he needs.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57308010/3238085